# Change of variables Levy process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $L$ be a Lévy process and define $M_t:=L_t-t\mathbb E(L(1)),$ then $M$ is a centred martingale.

Now consider the stochastic integral for $f$ a continuous process

$$\int_0^t f(t-s) \ dM_s,$$

is it then true that this is equal $\int_0^t f(s)\ dM_s$ almost surely?

I believe the answer should be yes, because of a linear change of variables is compatible with the iid increments.

Comment: It won't be equal a.s.  But equal in distribution is plausible.

Comment: @NateEldredge equal in distribution looks reasonable, I agree. Does plausible mean you are sure?

Comment: If I was sure I would have posted an answer :-)  At this point I'm just trying to help improve the question.